# Close event of Angular UI Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to write some code on selection of Date in Angular UI Boostrap DatePicker.

I tried using ng-change event as below. but it doesn't call when date is not changed. Even if we can detect close event of popup that will also be helpful.

```
ctrl.changeDate = function() {
    console.log('called date');
}
```

My HTML Code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    uib-datepicker-popup="{{'dd/MM/yyyy'}}"
    ng-model="$ctrl.model[$ctrl.name]"  
    ng-show="$ctrl.editMode"
    is-open="$ctrl.popup1.opened"
    datepicker-options="{dateDisabled: disabled,formatYear: 'yy',startingDay: 1}"
    close-text="Close" 
    alt-input-formats="['dd/MM/yyyy']" 
    ng-focus="$ctrl.open1()"
    ng-change="$ctrl.changeDate()" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch opened property for detect close event

```
$scope.$watch('$ctrl.popup1.opened',function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal != oldVal && !newVal){
         //close event
    }
})
```